# jQuery compare key of one array with value of another array and return match

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

Using $.getJSON to get data from external .json file with following content.

```js
{
    "title_12345":"<span class=\"header-class\">Header</span>",
    "p_12345":"<span class=\"description-class\">description</span>",
    "p_23456":"Another paragraph",
    "p_34567":"Another second paragraph",
    "desc": [
        "title_12345", 
        "p_12345",  
        {
            "ul_12345": [
                "li_1", 
                "li_2"
            ]
        },
        "p_23456",  
        {
            "ul_12345": [
                "li_3",
                {
                  "ul_23456": [
                    "li_6",
                    "li_7"
                  ]
                }, 
                "li_4",
                "li_5"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "li_1":"Listing One",
    "li_2":"Listing Two",
    "li_3":"Another Listing",
    "li_4":"Another Second Listing",
    "li_5":"Another Thrid Listing",
    "li_6":"Sub One Listing",
    "li_7":"Sub Two Listing"
}
```

What I want to achieve is as following.
Create a new object based on "desc" array with matching pair key-value.

```js
"desc": [
    "title_12345":"<span class=\"header-class\">Header</span>", 
    "p_12345":"<span class=\"description-class\">Description</span>",  
    {
        "ul_12345": [
            "li_1":"Listing One",
            "li_2":"Listing Two"
        ]
    },
    "p_23456":"Another paragraph",  
    {
        "ul_23456": [
            "li_3":"Another Listing",
            {
              "ul_23456": [
                "li_6":"Sub One Listing",
                "li_7":"Sub Two Listing"
              ]
            },
            "li_4":"Another Second Listing"
            "li_5":"Another Thrid Listing"
        ]
    }
]
```

And with the new "desc" object, create html content to append to a html page.
**Note that the "desc" array = the DOM hierarchy of return data**

if key contain "title_" , print value inside a `<h4>` (without `<span>`). Result: `<h4>Header</h4>`

if key contain "p_", print value inside a `<p>` (without `<span>`). Result: `<p>Description</p>`

if key contain "ul_", print each object inside a `<li>` loop. Result: `<ul><li>Listing One</li><li>Listing Two</li></ul>`

This will be the final result to append on the page

```js
<h4>Header</h4>
<p>Description</p>
<ul>
    <li>Listing One</li>
    <li>Listing Two</li>
</ul>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<ul>
    <li>Another Listing</li>
        <ul>
           <li>Sub One Listing</li> 
           <li>Sub Two Listing</li>
        </ul>
    <li>Another Second Listing</li>
</ul>
```

Any idea how to achieve this result using jQuery? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"What I want to achieve is matching the "desc" array value with data pair key-value like following..."_ - I want to note that what you show below this statement is invalid JSON. Arrays ***cannot*** have properties. Only objects can. To get what you want, you'll need to convert `desc` to an object and then nest the two inner objects in an additional array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take out the `desc` array from your JSON data and go through the it like below-

```
var temp = YOURJSONDATA;
var desc = temp.desc;
var results = {};
var htmlString = '';
$.each(desc, function(index, item) {
    if(typeof item === 'object') {
      Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
          htmlString += '<ul>';
                $.each(item[key], function(innerIndex, innerItem) {
            if(!results.hasOwnProperty(key)) results[key] = Array();
            results[key][innerItem] = temp.hasOwnProperty(innerItem) ? temp[innerItem] : '';
            console.log(results[key][innerItem]);
            htmlString += getHtmlForKey(innerItem, results[key][innerItem]);
          });
          htmlString +='</ul>';
            });
    } else {
        results[item] = temp.hasOwnProperty(item) ? temp[item] : '';
        htmlString += getHtmlForKey(item, results[item]);
    }
});
function getHtmlForKey(key, value) {
    if(key.indexOf('title_') !== -1) { return "<h4>"+getData(value)+"</h4>"; }
    if(key.indexOf('p_') !== -1) { return "<p>"+getData(value)+"</p>"; }
    if(key.indexOf('li_') !== -1) { return "<li>"+getData(value)+"</li>"; }
}
function getData(str) {
    var testElement= document.createElement('testElement');
    testElement.innerHTML= str;
    return testElement.textContent || testElement.innerText;
} 
//htmlString variable now contains the final HTML string.
```

Please note that the `$(value).text()` function helps in stripping the HTML tags, so use it wherever you just need the text without html tags.

Here is a fiddle to see this in action - https://jsfiddle.net/schikara/0kf7ht3w/8/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort. I could not change the external json format. Had to keep the "desc" array. And the result need to be print on the html based on the "desc" array hierarchy.
Updated https://jsfiddle.net/0kf7ht3w/1/ , notice the "p_23456" is not rendering any value. Was it because the htmlString was format to print header, description,listing only?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot @Shekhar

Comment: @ Shekhar could you advice if there is another sub listing inside a li.
Example https://jsfiddle.net/0kf7ht3w/12/ -> got error on console log TypeError: key.indexOf is not a function. (In 'key.indexOf('title_')', 'key.indexOf' is undefined)

Comment: @ Shekhar , I got it to run now https://jsfiddle.net/0kf7ht3w/15/ -> if there is way to improve it kindly let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are requring, you have to first parse the JSON as per your requirment then extract the text content from **span** from main data. Finaaly you should append this in some variable and make it visible in your page. Beloa is the sample impementation

Here we are getting JSON and extracting data from main content as per values we have in **desc** array. We are appending **li** data in **list** variable and rest of the things will go in **html** variable.

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(result){
    var arr = result.desc;
    var html="",list="<ul>";
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){                  
        if(typeof(arr[i])=='object'){
            for (var key in arr[i]){
                if(key.indexOf("ul_")!=-1){
                    var liItems = arr[i][key];
                    for(var j=0;j<liItems.length;j++){
                        list+="<li>"+extractText(result[liItems[j]])+"</li>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(arr[i].indexOf("title_")!=-1){
            html+="<h4>"+extractText(result[arr[i]])+"</h4>";
        }
        else if(arr[i].indexOf("p_")!=-1){
            html+="<p>"+extractText(result[arr[i]])+"</p>";
        }
    }
    list+="</ul>"
    html+=list;
    $("#showHtml").html(html); // show final html whereever you want.

});
```

I have created below function for extracting text content from the span :

```
function extractText(s) {
    var span= document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML= s;
    return span.textContent || span.innerText;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One additional requirement is the return result of html would need to follow the hierarchy as defined in "desc" array. I update my original question. Kindly take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
// Helper function to check if variable is an object(i,e.. {})
function isObject(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]'
}

// Parent for append elements
var parent = $("#parent")

// JSON data
var json = {
    "title_12345": "<span class=\"header-class\">Header</span>",
    "p_12345": "<span class=\"description-class\">Description</span>",
    "p_23456": "Another paragraph",
    "desc": [
        "title_12345",
        "p_12345",
        {
            "ul_12345": [
                "li_1",
                "li_2",
            ]
        },
        "p_23456",
        {
            "ul_131233": [
                "li_21",
                "li_22",
            ]
        }

    ],
    "li_1": "Listing One",
    "li_2": "Listing Two",
    "li_21": "Another Listing",
    "li_22": "Another second paragraph",
}

// Mapping of html tags to be used
var htmltags = {
    'title': 'h4',
    'p': 'p',
    'ul': 'ul',
    'li': 'li'
}

// Iterating over desc, maintains level
json["desc"].forEach(function (element) {

    // Calls approprite method to handle given element
    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
        parseArray(element)
    } else if (isObject(element)) {
        parseObject(element)
    } else {
        var child = document.createElement(htmltags[element.split('_')[0]])
        child.innerHTML = $(json[element]).text() || json[element] || ""
        parent.append(child)
    }
})

function parseArray(element) {
    element.forEach(function (item) {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            parseArray(item)
        } else if (isObject(item)) {
            parseObject(item)
        } else {
            var child = document.createElement(htmltags[item.split('_')[0]])
            child.innerHTML = $(json[item]).text() || json[item] || ""
            parent.append(child)
        }
    })

}

function parseObject(element) {
    Object.keys(element).forEach(function (key) {
        if (Array.isArray(element[key])) {
            var child = document.createElement(htmltags[key.split('_')[0]])
            parent.append(child)
            parent = child
            parseArray(element[key])
            parent = $("#parent")

        } else if (isObject(element[key])) {
            parseObject(element[key])
        } else {
            var child = document.createElement(htmltags[element[key].split('_')[0]])
            child.innerHTML = $(json[element[key]]).text() || ""
            parent.append(child)

        }
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Priyesh. I added your code to https://jsfiddle.net/0kf7ht3w/10/ and it works well